# Specify variable type is redundant

Tags: typescript

I just start coding with TypeScript. So I'm trying to pick good practices within this language.

Is it a good practice to spesfy variable type when it is known?

For example, in this code:

```
var myVar: string = "";
```

Why adding `string` type as it is obvious that `myVar` is an empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type inference ( https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html ) allows you to omit typing on one-liner initialization.

So in this case

```
var myVar = "";
```

would be sufficient, and correctly interpreted as string by the compiler.

However without the `""` affectation, an explicit typing would be necessary to make it a string.